# How to parse elements and print them in TreeView in javafx

Tags: java, treeview, javafx

i am having a treeview and a button on my GUI. In TreeView i populated TreeItems. Now my TreeView Structure is as follows:

```
Employee

 Smith
 John
 Alex
 Michel
```

In employee i am having these four items.

Now on clicking Button. I should parse TreeView Items and print all items for employee.

Here my doubt is how to get children's of root node.

Answer (score 0):

See my sample:

```
public class TreeViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Construct tree
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String>("Employers");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String>("Employer " + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>(rootItem);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        //Reading tree
        TreeItem<String> rootItem2 = tree.getRoot();
        ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> childrens = rootItem2.getChildren();
        for (TreeItem<String> treeItem : childrens) {
            System.out.println(treeItem.getValue());
        }


    }
}
```